# Failed to submit transaction: Error: no suitable peers available to initialize from

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I am running my blockchain project which is election system using blockchain using hyperledger fabric and IBM blockchain Platform VSCode Extension (runnning my network locally). I am successfull to run connect to local fabric and my gateway is running successfully(image attached). Also all docker containers of peer,orderer,certificate authority are running (image attached).

[connected to local fabric and gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8H2l.png)

[all docker containers running successfuly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dTmc.png)

The problem which I am facing is that when (after connecting to local fabric and gateway) I am running invoke.js file using the command "node invoke.js" I am encountering above error. following picture link shows how I am running invoke.js

[trying to run invoke.js but facing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYPpc.png)

following is my config.json file code

```
    {
  "connection_file": "fabric_connection.json",
  "appAdmin": "admin",
  "appAdminSecret": "adminpw",
  "orgMSPID": "org1MSP",
  "caName": "ca",
  "userName": "V1",
  "gatewayDiscovery": { "enabled": true, "asLocalhost": true }
}
```

and following is my fabric-connection.json file code

```
{
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "caName": "ca",
            "url": "http://localhost:17090"
        }
    },
    "client": {
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "orderer": "300",
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        },
        "organization": "Org1MSP"
    },
    "name": "ca.org1.example.com",
    "organizations": {
        "Org1MSP": {
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "Org1Peer1"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "Org1Peer1": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:17091"
        }
    },
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

and following is my invoke.js file complete code

```
//Import Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 programming model - fabric-network
'use strict';

const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

//connect to the config file
const configPath = path.join(process.cwd(), './config.json');
const configJSON = fs.readFileSync(configPath, 'utf8');
const config = JSON.parse(configJSON);

// connect to the connection file
const ccpPath = path.join(process.cwd(), './ibpConnection.json');
const ccpJSON = fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8');
const connectionProfile = JSON.parse(ccpJSON);

// A wallet stores a collection of identities for use
const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), './wallet');
const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

const peerIdentity = 'admin';

async function queryAll() {
  
  try {

    let response;

    // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
    const userExists = await wallet.exists(peerIdentity);
    if (!userExists) {
      console.log('An identity for the user ' + peerIdentity + ' does not exist in the wallet');
      console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
      response.error = 'An identity for the user ' + peerIdentity + ' does not exist in the wallet. Register ' + peerIdentity + ' first';
      return response;
    }

    //connect to Fabric Network, but starting a new gateway
    const gateway = new Gateway();

    //use our config file, our peerIdentity, and our discovery options to connect to Fabric network.
    await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, { wallet, identity: peerIdentity, discovery: config.gatewayDiscovery });

    //connect to our channel that has been created on IBM Blockchain Platform
    const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

    //connect to our insurance contract that has been installed / instantiated on IBM Blockchain Platform
    const contract = await network.getContract('voteChainDemo'); 
    //submit transaction to the smart contract that is installed / instnatiated on the peers
    console.log('calling contract.evaluateTransaction, with args');
    response = await contract.submitTransaction('queryAll');
    response = JSON.parse(response.toString());
    console.log(`response from evaluateTransaction: ${(response)}`)
   

    console.log('Transaction has been submitted');

    // Disconnect from the gateway.
    await gateway.disconnect();

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to submit transaction: ${error}`);
  }
}
// let args = ["V1"]
// args = args.toString();
queryAll();
```

and I see following logs when I view docker container logs of peer0.org1.example.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwnme.png)

following is the code of ibpconnection.json file

```
{
  "name": "mychannel",
  "description": "Network on IBP v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "client": {
      "organization": "org1MSP"
  },
  "organizations": {
      "org1MSP": {
          "mspid": "org1MSP",
          "peers": [
              "173.193.112.109:17091"
          ],
          "certificateAuthorities": [
              "173.193.112.109:7054"
          ]
      }
  },
  "orderers": {
      "173.193.112.109:7050": {
          "url": "grpcs://173.193.112.109:17097",
          "tlsCACerts": {
              "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICJzCCAc6gAwIBAgIUCZxOyrvnwM/IG/3zQ9opnOE/gBEwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw\nZTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAgTDk5vcnRoIENhcm9saW5hMRQwEgYDVQQK\nEwtIeXBlcmxlZGdlcjEPMA0GA1UECxMGRmFicmljMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1PcmRlcmVy\nQ0EtdGxzMB4XDTE5MDYxNDIwNDcwMFoXDTM0MDYxMDIwNDcwMFowZTELMAkGA1UE\nBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAgTDk5vcnRoIENhcm9saW5hMRQwEgYDVQQKEwtIeXBlcmxl\nZGdlcjEPMA0GA1UECxMGRmFicmljMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1PcmRlcmVyQ0EtdGxzMFkw\nEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEOXI7XkoPBn7a9Q1x2S8SpmilQBalhorq\nCo96GChxQU0HJX/1qRPNN72CKx2YS/ksl+eOaHe/+pH32S5VWZLxaKNcMFowDgYD\nVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQEwHQYDVR0OBBYEFIdV28CJ\nPozrl6hpxVkKpNdmAO7vMBUGA1UdEQQOMAyHBK3BcG2HBApM2GAwCgYIKoZIzj0E\nAwIDRwAwRAIgTOPmbGXzIL8SriNT/x8XdBLoTbpEVd/HIpv9nf0bWysCIBvOppOp\nvINgCydCwV1FTbP5tuqYxuShVTAba1h9ZZmm\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
          }
      }
  },
  "peers": {
      "173.193.112.109:17091": {
          "url": "grpcs://173.193.112.109:17093",
          "tlsCACerts": {
              "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n50KrbM4ayRuaFBOFL88FflKxaRjQels=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
          },
          "grpcOptions": {
              "ssl-target-name-override": "173.193.112.109"
          }
      }
  },
  "certificateAuthorities": {
      "173.193.112.109:7054": {
          "url": "https://173.193.112.109:17090",
          "caName": "ca",
          "tlsCACerts": {
              "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\r\nBShP1pNsvsyOctmFhQCQ\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show you connection config and the relevant part of invoke.js where the exception is thrown. Also, can you see any reaction in the peer container's logs?

Comment: sure, I have modified the question and provided config.json, local-fabric.json and invoke.js code

Comment: also added the container's logs for peer0.org1.example.com

Comment: why can't the peer connect to the orderer? any hints in the orderer log?

Comment: can't figure out. I think the issue is in ibpconnection.json file which I have added now in the question.

Comment: just for completeness: did you check that you can ping the orderer and connect to the port with netcat or the like?

Comment: no I have not checked that. But I will do that now.

Answer (score 0):

In my project which is pretty much having the same things as you, I did not specified the `orderers` in my connection config file. I am not sure if it is required in your scenario.

Besides, I think the issue is caused by incorrect urls specified in your `ibpconnection.json`file.

`orderers` should have `"url": "grpcs://173.193.112.109:7050"`

AND

`peers` should have `"url": "grpcs://173.193.112.109:17091"`

Hope this will fix the error. Good luck!!!!

Comment: Also, maybe change:
`"ssl-target-name-override": "173.193.112.109"` to `"ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"`